# Different ways to return string value

Tags: c++

so I have this function where I need to pass the string "1" and I have 2 ways to do it:

```
String func(){
  String result = "1";
  return result;
}
```

and:

```
String func(){
   String result = SerializeAsString(1);
   return result;
}
```

where:

```
inline std::string SerializeAsString(const T& obj) {
        return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&obj), sizeof(obj));
    }
```

I know it might be a stupid Q, but which way of coding is considered better?

Thank you

Comment: We can't tell you which is better as they do two completely different things.

Comment: won't SerializeAsString return a "1" string?

Comment: @O.San, no. It will return it's binary  representation, which is probably not what you expect.

Comment: @O.San [No](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e8bd3ce92171875)

Comment: Use a std::string and return it. std::strings are vectors underneath, and modern C++ allows for very efficient creation and returning of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first method. I do not see the point of method 2. In my experiance keeping things simple and readable is the best coding style.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing "1" - you are returning from function. If you need to return "1" from a function you can simply do

```
String func(){
    ....
    return "1";
}
```

no need to store the value of "1" in some variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first method you listed is standard for *most* string functions.

```
String foo(){
string bar = "This is my string";
return bar;
}
```

**Returns:** "This is my string"

or

```
String foo(){
//Your code here...
return "bar";
}
```

**Returns:** "bar"

There is no real way that is necessarily better than another, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. For simple strings, I usually prefer this method because it is clean and simple.